# Scanf delimiter and empty string

Tags: c

I'm having a problem reading in values using sscanf() with delimiters.

```
sscanf(line, "%15[^:]:%20[^:]:%d:%d:%50[^:]:%25[^:]:%25[^\n]",
       string1, string2, &value1, &value2, string3, string4, string5);
```

There's only a problem when line is something like:

```
abc:defg:1:2::hijk:no
```

When I print out the strings/values, everything is normal up until 'string 3'. It outputs some weird character, then 'string4' outputs an empty space and string5 outputs a similar weird character.

Anybody have any idea how I can scan in the right values?

edit: I meant abc:defg:1:2::hijk:no, not abc:defg:1:2::hijk:lm:no

Comment: do not edit your question this way, it invalidates the answers..

Comment: Can you post the output you are getting and also the desired output?

Comment: If I read in a text file with abc:defg:1:2::hijk:no for my output I would get:

abc | defg | 1 | 2 | (weird character) | | (weird character)

the desired output would be:

abc | defg | 1 | 2 | | hijk | no

I'll try to find a picture of the character, hold on.

Comment: use `strsep` for parse.

Comment: Use `std::regex`, now you have two problems :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the return value from `scanf()` calls

```
errno = 0;
int chk = sscanf(line, "%15[^:]:%20[^:]:%d:%d:%50[^:]:%25[^:]:%25[^\n]",
       string1, string2, &value1, &value2, string3, string4, string5);
switch (chk) {
    case 7: /* all ok */;
            break;
    case 6:
    case 5:
    case 4:
    case 3:
    case 2:
    case 1:
    case 0: /* not enough variabes were assigned a value */;
            break;
    case EOF: /* error reading data */;
              /* use ferror() and/or feof() and errno to determine cause of error */;
              break;
    default: /* no other cases are possible */;
             break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `[` specifier causes *matching failure* if it does not match any characters. The `scanf` function stops reading when a matching failure occurs.

The garbage you see is because you are printing out uninitialized variables (the scanning never got so far as to fill in those variables).

If you want to allow zero or more characters for a character field, you can't use a string with `%[` followed by some other stuff.

Alternatives include:

- Make several separate calls to `scanf` which keep going even if the previous one failed
- Don't use scanf  (probably simpler in the long run).

A regex library might be the simplest option.

Answer (score 1):

try this..( `&` is missing for scanning `int`)

`sscanf(line, "%15[^:]:%20[^:]:%d:%d:%50[^:]:%25[^:]:%25[^\n]",
       string1, string 2, &value1, &value2, string3, string4, string5);`

Comment: My bad, I'm tired and I rewrote the code. I had that in my original code.

Answer (score 0):

use `strsep` like below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strsep(char **sp, const char *sep);

int main(){
    char line[] = "abc:defg:1:2::hijk:no\n";
    int value1, value2;
    char string1[16];
    char string2[20];
    char string3[51];
    char string4[26];
    char string5[26];
    char *p = line;
/*
    sscanf(line, "%15[^:]:%20[^:]:%d:%d:%50[^:]:%25[^:]:%25[^\n]",
        string1, string2, &value1, &value2, string3, string4, string5);
*/
    strcpy(string1, strsep(&p, ":"));//or strncpy, etc. 
    strcpy(string2, strsep(&p, ":"));
    value1 = atoi(strsep(&p, ":"));
    value2 = atoi(strsep(&p, ":"));
    strcpy(string3, strsep(&p, ":"));
    strcpy(string4, strsep(&p, ":"));
    strcpy(string5, strsep(&p, ":\n"));
    printf("%s %s %d %d \"%s\" %s %s\n",
        string1, string2, value1, value2, string3, string4, string5);
    return 0;
}
```

See the following links for `strsep`.
[strsep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strsep)

`strsep` is not a standard function.
if it does not exist,  be implemented as follows(E.g) :

```
char *strsep(char **sp, const char *sep){
    char *p, *s;
    if (sp == NULL || *sp == NULL || **sp == '\0') return(NULL);
    s = *sp;
    p = s + strcspn(s, sep);
    if (*p != '\0') *p++ = '\0';
    *sp = p;
    return(s);
}
```